# Site list should also be reversely sortable

Tags: feature-request, sorting, communities-list

The list of all StackExchange sites (at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) can be sorted by *Traffic, Oldest, Newest, Questions, Answers, Percent Answered, Users, Questions Per Day and their Name*.

The *Oldest* and *Newest* options are opposites, but for every other sorting option no opposite sorting method exists. I suggest that there should be another toggle for reversing the lists order.

This toggle could be located next to the other sorting options:

[image]

Comment: Why? You can just go to the bottom of the page and go up the list.

Comment: @Laurel It simplifies things and that is the reason technology exists for (in my opinion). Why would you implement a search feature for StackOverflow if you can just scroll throgh the list and look for the question you are looking for? ^^

Comment: The ability to sort on [more than one column and other features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3rv4.jpg) like a [parts list](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11814#/sort=1746,desc) would improve this request; over one basic ability inconveniently offered by the scrollbar.

Comment: @Rob Yes, the scrollbar, or even faster: the `End` key.

Comment: @user289905 "Scrollbar" was used generically, as mobile users don't have one on that page, and unless you install a [`Hacker's Keyboard`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) your handicap doesn't [`Ctrl`+`End`](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/ctrl-end.htm) there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding another toggle to reverse the sorting would require an overhaul of that view without a clear benefit.

The easiest thing that could work and wouldn't require a ton of dev time, in [sites.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/stackexchange/js/sites.js) find `function initializeListView()`  and change the `getSortData` object to:

```js
getSortData: {
    oldest: function (elem) { return parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="creation-date"]').val(), 10); },
    newest: function (elem) { return -parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="creation-date"]').val(), 10); },
    questions: function (elem) { return -parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="questions"]').val(), 10); },
    answers: function (elem) { return -parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="answers"]').val(), 10); },
    percentanswered: function (elem) { return -parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="percent-answered"]').val()); },
    users: function (elem) { return -parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="users"]').val(), 10); },
    traffic: function (elem) { return -parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="visits-per-day"]').val()); },
    questionsperday: function (elem) { return -parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="questions-per-day"]').val()); },
    name: function (elem) { return $(elem).find('input[name="name"]').val(); },
    // sort almost all the things
    questionsasc: function (elem) { return parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="questions"]').val(), 10); },
    answersasc: function (elem) { return parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="answers"]').val(), 10); },
    percentansweredasc: function (elem) { return parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="percent-answered"]').val()); },
    usersasc: function (elem) { return parseInt($(elem).find('input[name="users"]').val(), 10); },
    trafficasc: function (elem) { return parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="visits-per-day"]').val()); },
    questionsperdayasc: function (elem) { return parseFloat($(elem).find('input[name="questions-per-day"]').val()); },
}
```

And then in the list view add more options to the site-sort dropdown:

```html
<select class="site-sort">
        <option value="traffic" selected="selected">Traffic</option>
        <option value="trafficasc">Ghost towns</option>
        <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
        <option value="newest">Newest</option>
        <option value="questions">Questions</option>
        <option value="questionsasc">Hardly any Questions</option>
        <option value="answers">Answers</option>
        <option value="answersasc">Lacking Answers</option>
        <option value="percentanswered">Percent Answered</option>
        <option value="percentansweredasc">Lowest Percent Answered</option>
        <option value="users">Users</option>
        <option value="usersasc">From no Users to all Users</option>
        <option value="questionsperday">Questions Per Day</option>
        <option value="questionsperdayasc">Reversed Questions Per Day</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
</select>
```

(Maybe needs better wording for the sort options)

I've done the work that is needed. If this is really useful then a dev needs to make those  changes the code base, test, merge, get it reviewed and deployed. Allow for at least 6 to 8 weeks before this happens, if at all.

I'm not convinced the alternate sort orders are that useful or beneficial for regular visitors of that page.

Last time I heard news about those pages I was told they were going away / getting redesigned anyway. Maybe sorting /filtering gets some new love as well then.